# Reference of a method while creating the prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I feel a bit dump but there is something I don't understand (or even know if it's possible) about prototyping in JavaScript.
I'd like to use a method while I'm creating the prototype of my pseudo-class :

```
var Class = function() {}
Class.prototype = {
    a: function() {
        return 'ok'
    }
  , z: Class.prototype.a() // I tried with `this`/`constructor`/etc.
} // TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'a' the rest isn't evaluated
var test = new Class()
test.z
```

I know I can do it this way but I'd like to know if I can still but all my method/properties in the `Class.prototype` declaration :

```
var Class = function() {}
Class.prototype.a = function() {
    return 'ok'
}
Class.prototype.z = Class.prototype.a()
var test = new Class()
test.z // "ok"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Just like you can't refer to any object properties before the statement that defines them has ended:

```
var x = {
    y: 10,
    z: x.y + 5 // TypeError, cannot read property `y` of undefined
};
```

The variable `x` does not have a value (it *is* declared, since declarations are hoisted, but it's value is `undefined`) until the assignment expression in its entirety has been evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can assign `Class` like this:

```
var Class = function() {
 if (!Class.prototype.a){
  var proto = Class.prototype;
  proto.a = function() {
     return 'ok';
  };
  proto.z = proto.a();
 }
}

var test = new Class;
console.log(test.z); //=> "ok"
```

Another option could be to use a singleton to create the prototype properties/methods:

```
var Class = function(){};
Class.prototype = function(){
  function a(){return 'ok';}
  return {a: a, z: a()};
}();
var test = new Class;
console.log(test.z); //=> "ok"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one additional property to add, you can do this:

```
(Class.prototype = {
    a: function() {
        return 'ok'
    }
}).z = Class.prototype.a();
```

---

Or you could take this approach, which uses an anonymous function as a temporary constructor:

```
Class.prototype = new function() {
    this.a = function() {
        return 'ok'
    }
    this.z = this.a()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: the accepted answer is wrong. You can.

Second: ever seen the following pattern?

```
Class.prototype = {
    constructor: Class
};
```

The `constructor` property is necessary if you want to access the current object using `this`.

Third: if you're not in the property function, the context is `window`, (`undefined` in strict mode), not the object.

Fourth: this is what you're looking for:

```
function Class() {}

Class.prototype = {
    constructor: Class, // required!

    a: function() {
        return 'ok';
    },

    z: function() {
        // 'this' is the object *in* the function
        return this.a();
    }
};

var o = new Class();
console.log(o.z()); // "ok"
```

Comment: I'd agree that the selected answer is wrong. Your solution though, doesn't show 'ok' because the method `z` doesn't return anything, and is not what te OP asked.